# Jquery Returning number in new line

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the int value from h4 and then add 2 in that, it should return value 123125, but the issue I am having is when I am getting the text from h4 and replacing the ',' with '' it is showing every number in a new line

```
var GetFirstUserCount = $("#GetFirstUserCount").text();
```

[image]

after removing the ',' it shows only first charter

```
alert( $("#GetFirstUserCount").text().replace(',',''));
```

[image]

```
  <p><h4 id="GetFirstUserCount" class="card-title odometer">123,123</h4></p>



 var GetFirstUserCountCost = parseInt(GetFirstUserCount) + 2 ;
 $('#GetFirstUserCount').text(GetFirstUserCountCost)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

The correct code should be:

```
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      <p><h4 id="GetFirstUserCount" class="card-title odometer">123,123</h4></p>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var GetFirstUserCount = $("#GetFirstUserCount").text();
            GetFirstUserCount = $("#GetFirstUserCount").text().replace(',','');
            var GetFirstUserCountCost = parseInt(GetFirstUserCount) + 2 ;
            $('#GetFirstUserCount').text(GetFirstUserCountCost)
          })
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should also highlight which part of the code is wrong.

Comment: It's not necessary when the full code is wrong. It means, the syntax is not the correct way! If it had been a little mistake, I could otherwise, it's better to display full code.